# sympy.linsolve produces wrong result

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Consider the system of coupled, linear, algebraic equations:
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhegI.png)

The solution set is infinite with:
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KroDM.png)

Attempting to solve this system using sympy gives an incorrect result of the form:
[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5yJM.png)

Python code to reproduce incorrect result:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy

A = np.array([[1,1,0,1,1,-3,-1,1,],[0,0,0,-1,-1,0,-1,-2,],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,]])
b = np.array([[0],[0],[0]])

variable_symbols = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

#Convert to sympy matrix
A_sympy = sympy.Matrix(A)
b_sympy = sympy.Matrix(b)

#Make sympy symbols
syms = sympy.symbols(variable_symbols)
syms = list(syms)

#Solve system
sol_sympy = sympy.linsolve((A_sympy,b_sympy),syms)#Problem is here
print(sol_sympy)
```

The output is:

```
FiniteSet((-b - g - 2*h, b, c, -c - g - 2*h, e, -g - h, g, h))
```

Which gives the incorrect solution space of [pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5yJM.png).

The output should instead be:

```
FiniteSet((-b - g - 2*h, b, c, -e - g - 2*h, e, -g - h, g, h))
```

Edit:
It was suggested that perhaps the solutions are identical, but written in different forms. But I don't think this is the case.

Consider a solution from the correct expression [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KroDM.png) of the form b=0, c=1, e=0, g=0, h=0, This gives: a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0, e=0,f=0, g=0

NOTE: h,g,e,c,b are equal to alpha1,2,3,4,5 respectively.

Now consider obtaining the same solution, "a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0, e=0,f=0, g=0" but using the sympy expression [pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5yJM.png). It cannot be done.

**Update & Solution:**
Error was produced using sympy 1.6.1. But an update to 1.7.1+ fixed the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the result is incorrect? There are many different ways to represent the same solution set of an underdetermined system of equations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If there is something that could be improved within SymPy here then it is best to discuss that on GitHub: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with Sympy 1.7.1 and Python 3.7.12. Your code  output matches the expected output.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem the error was produced using sympy 1.6.1. I have upgraded to 1.10 and the error went away for me as well. It appears that earlier versions of sympy had this issue.: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18208